# Android - Periodic Background Service - Advice

Tags: android, service

I am working on an app that will relay information about its location to a remote server. I am intending to do it by doing a simple HTTP post to the web-server and all is simple and fine.

But according to the spec, the app needs to execute itself from time to time, lets say once in every 30 mins. Be independent of the interface, meaning which it needs to run even if the app is closed.

I looked around and found out that Android Services is what needs to be used. What could I use to implement such a system. Will the service (or other mechanism) restart when the phone restarts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Create a `Service` to send your information to your server.  Presumably, you've got that under control.

Your `Service` should be started by an alarm triggered by the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), where you can specify an interval.  Unless you have to report your data *exactly* every 30 minutes, you probably want the inexact alarm so you can save some battery life.

Finally, you can register your app to get the bootup broadcast by setting up a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) like so:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            // Register your reporting alarms here.            
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the following permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` for that to work.  Don't forget to register your alarms when you run the app normally, or they'll only be registered when the device boots up.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is a semi-different way to keep the service going forever. There is ways to kill it in code if you'd wish

Background Service:

```
package com.ex.ample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    public Context context = this;
    public Handler handler = null;
    public static Runnable runnable = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Service is still running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        /* IF YOU WANT THIS SERVICE KILLED WITH THE APP THEN UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE */
        //handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is how you start it from your main activity or wherever you wish:

```
startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));
```

`onDestroy()` will get called when the application gets closed or killed but the runnable just starts it right back up.

I hope this helps someone out.

The reason why some people do this is because of corporate applications where in some instances the users/employees must not be able to stop certain things :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOp3q.png

---

### **EDIT**

Since Android O (8.0) you have to use `JobManager` for scheduled tasks. There is a library called [Android-Job by Evernote](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) which will make periodic background work a breeze on all Android versions. I have also made a [Xamarin Binding](https://github.com/Dooks123/Android-Job-XamarinBinding) of this library.

Then all you need to do is the following:

In your application class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new MyJobCreator());
    }
}
```

Create the following two classes `YourJobCreator` and `YourSyncJob`(Where all the work will be done. Android allocates time for all the background jobs to be run. For android versions < 8.0 it will still run with an Alarm manager and background service as per normal)

```
public class MyJobCreator implements JobCreator {

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case MySyncJob.TAG:
                return new MySyncJob();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

public class MySyncJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAG = "my_job_tag";

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
        //
        // run your job here
        //
        //
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    public static void scheduleJob() {
        new JobRequest.Builder(MySyncJob.TAG)
                .setExecutionWindow(30_000L, 40_000L) //Every 30 seconds for 40 seconds
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice workaround, but this will keep starting the handler after some time, as the service will get started again after some time.

Comment: To prevent restart move the code from onCreate() to 
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //code for runnable
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

return START_NOT_STICKY will make sure that the service will not restart and your handler will remain stopped after onDestroyed().

Comment: Don't forget to add the service to your `AndroidManifest.xml`: `<service android:name=".services.MyService" android:label="MyService" ></service>`.

Comment: @KTWorks This used to work on older Android Versions. You need to use something like https://github.com/evernote/android-job - With the correct settings, you can have the job run indefinitely without draining the user's battery. With Android O and up, you can not use StartService in the background anymore. All handlers are paused in Doze mode.

Answer (score 8):

You should schedule your service with alarm manager, first create the pending intent of service:

```
Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
PendingIntent pii = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 2222, ii,
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Then schedule it using alarm manager:

```
//getting current time and add 5 seconds to it
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
//registering our pending intent with alarmmanager
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

this will launch your service after 5 seconds of current time. You can make your alarm repeating.

Comment: Probably easier to do something like `System.currentTimeMillis() + TIMEOUT_MS` than mucking about with the `Calendar`, to get your initial delay.

Comment: You guys do know that you have static values in the AlarmManager for 1 day, 12 hours, 1 hour, half na hour and 15 minutes?
`public static final long INTERVAL_DAY`
`public static final long INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES`
`public static final long INTERVAL_HALF_DAY`
`public static final long INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR`
`public static final long INTERVAL_HOUR`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to start Service at specified time and then repeat alarm in specified interval. When alarm goes on you can start service and  connect to server and make what you want