# Using a wake lock with a service interval

Tags: android, android-service

Is it possible to have a service which only acquires a wake lock at set intervals to send information?

I would like to create a service that sends a location to a database every hour or whatever the user specifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably make use of the AlarmManager to trigger your service. 
See, for example, [Android - Periodic Background Service - Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420358/android-periodic-background-service-adivice)

Comment: The issue that I see with this solution is cancelling the alarmManager through cycles of the application. How could different activities cancel and reschedule the alarm?

Comment: They would use the cancel and setXXX methods of AlarmManager - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the documentation but a pendingIntent is used with a context which I assume would change through different activities and lifetimes of the application?