# How to make efficient android periodic background service

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I'm trying to develop an Android app that among other things, uses location services to get user location and sends it to a remote server. The user can turn this feature on and off according to his own will, but as long as it's turned on, it will get user location periodically (maybe each 30 seconds, don't know it for sure yet). Also, while it is turned on, it must keep tracking the user even if the application is closed.

So far I've considered 2 options:

**Option 1** - Use `Service`, call `startForeground` to make sure Android don't kill it (the sticky notification is not an issue to me) and use a `LocationListener` with the said interval, but this seems rather inefficient as the service would be doing nothing most of the time, I mean, the listener would be called each 30 seconds, send the location to the server and the service itself would spend the next 29.9 seconds or whatever just waiting for the next location.

**Option 2** - Doing some research, I've seen some approaches using `AlarmManager` to trigger some background service (like seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420358/android-periodic-background-service-advice)), but I'm concerned that using alarms that often (every 30 seconds) might not be good for the battery and system general performance (in a code snippet in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) page of Android's Developer guide there's a comment saying that "hopefully your alarm will have a frequency lower than 30 MINUTES").

Maybe there's another option that I still haven't thought about, or maybe there's a way to put the service from option 1 to sleep for some time or something like that. Bottom line, I'm looking for the approach that doesn't impacts on performance, consumes the minimum amount of battery and has the least chance of being killed by Android.

Any help and/or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I've had good results using `IntentService` and `PendingIntent` for this sort of task.  API Guide:  http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Brother , have you find the answer? I am also searching this answer.

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim I ended up using [Android Fused Location API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary) and `Android Activity Detection API`. The two APIs used together allowed me to capture user location with very low battery usage.