# How can I program a service as a separate process that performs its task periodically?

Tags: android, service, process, task, alarmmanager

I'm writing a program that scans a network, and I want it to run in the background regardless if the application is running or not. From what I've read the only way to have a service that continues after the application has been destroyed is one that runs on a separate process. I also want it to to perform this one task once every x minutes. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Periodic Background Service - Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420358/android-periodic-background-service-advice)

Answer (score 0):

Use `AlarmManager` api instead. It allows to run tasks periodically, even if app was not active since last boot.

[Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/scheduling/alarms.html)